# How many permutations of set are there with 4 fixed points?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion, fixed-points

Given the set of numbers $A = \left \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 \right \}$. How many permutations leave exactly four numbers fixed?

I've considered this as a solution... but then I stumbled upon a thought that I might count the same permutation multiple times.

$$8! - \binom{8}{4}\left | \bigcup_{i=1}^{4}A_{i} \right |$$ ?

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is more complicated than that: you can use inclusion-exclusion or look at *[rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)*

Comment: how many subsets of four numbers are there?  For each, how many derangements of the remaining four numbers are there?

Comment: I don't understand your solution. What is $A_i$??

Answer (score 0):

With the purpose of getting a value to verify our work we obtain
using combinatorial classes the following
class $\mathcal{P}$  of permutations with fixed points marked:

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{P} = \textsc{SET}(
\mathcal{U} \times \textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z}) +
\textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})  +
\textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})  + \cdots).$$

This gives the EGF

$$F(z, u) = \exp\left(uz+\frac{z^2}{2}
+ \frac{z^3}{3}
+ \frac{z^4}{4}
+ \cdots \right)
\\ = \exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z} + (u-1)z\right)
= \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left((u-1)z\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left(-z\right)
\exp\left(uz\right).$$

Hence permutations with exactly $k$ fixed points have EGF

$$G(z) = \frac{z^k}{k!} \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}.$$

Here we have $k=4$ and we get with $n=8$

$$8! [z^8] \frac{z^4}{4!} \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
= 1680 [z^4] \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
\\ = 1680 \sum_{q=0}^4 [z^q] \exp(-z) [z^{4-q}] \frac{1}{1-z}
= 1680 \sum_{q=0}^4 \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}
\\ = 1680 \left(\frac{1}{0!} - \frac{1}{1!}
+ \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{4!} \right)
= 630.$$

This is

$${8\choose 4} D_4$$

where $D_n = n! \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}$
counts [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).